# The ARCore dependency type com.google.ar.core is missing from the AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, google-play-console

I got this error [The ARCore dependency type com.google.ar.core is missing from the AndroidManifest.xml file although the meta-data tag com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version has been specified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYziH.png)
when I tried to upload my aab file onto google play console.

I have tried to add <<sup>xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"</sup> and (meta-data tools:replace="android:value" android:name="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version" android:value="19" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" /)<meta-data [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E1Nb.png)android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />> into my AndroidManifest.xml but this issue still persist. But this project does not even have ar core package.

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E1Nb.png)

Comment: Solved by changing ARCore Requirement to Optional in Vuforia Configuration.